# How to remove current marker on leaflet and add a new marker again?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm having a problem with my code. I'm displaying markers on my map, but instead of changing marker positions, it will just add new marker on my map.

I have a printscreen of my problem.

[image]

How do I remove the previous marker?

Here's my code:

```
var latB = 0;
var lonB = 0;
var mark = 0;
var marker = null;
function showOnMap(a){
    convert_location(a);
    marker = L.marker([latB, lonB]).bindPopup(a);
    map.removeLayer(marker)
    map.addLayer(marker);
}

function convert_location(a){
    var toData = (function (){
            var toData = null;
                $.ajax({
                    'async': false,
                    'global': false,
                    'url': 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=5&q='+a,
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'success': function(data){
                        toData = data;
                    }
                });
            return toData;
    })();

    $.each(toData, function(key, val){
        latB = val.lat;
        lonB = val.lon;
    });

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you can reproduce your issue on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), you would make people's understanding easier and it would enable them to directly show you how your code can be made working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are erasing marker after you set a reference to a new one, so basically you are removing non-existing new marker, and then adding it to the map.
Marker should be removed from map before it is reassigned.

```
function showOnMap(a){
  convert_location(a);
  if (marker != null) map.removeLayer(marker);
  marker = L.marker([latB, lonB]).bindPopup(a);
  map.addLayer(marker);
}
```